# Django: how to test type of RelatedManager?

Tags: django, django-managers

How to test the type of a RelatedManager in Django ?

```
assert type(qs) in [models.QuerySet, models.Manager]
```

fails if qs is a `RelatedManager`

how do I test if qs is a `RelatedManager` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found a solution:

```
assert isinstance(qs, (models.QuerySet, models.Manager))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of a related manager object by entering `type(some_related_manager_object)` in the shell. This returns `<class 'django.db.models.manager.Manager'>`.

To check if a queryset has type related manager object:

```
from django.db.models.manager import Manager

assert type(qs)==Manager
```